# Calculate Device seconds On using Kinesis Analytics

Tags: amazon-web-services, analytics, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm experimenting with Kinesis analytics and have solved many problems with it but actually stuck with the following:

I actually have a stream with records that reflects when a Device is turned on an off like:

`device_id   | timestamp        | reading
   1         | 2011/09/01 22:30 | 1
   1         | 2011/09/01 23:00 | 0
   1         | 2011/09/02 03:30 | 1
   1         | 2011/09/02 03:31 | 0`

- I'm using 1 for On and 0 for Off in the `reading` field.

What I'm trying to accomplish is create a PUMP that redirects the number of seconds a Device has been on every 5 minutes window to another stream looking like:

`device_id   | timestamp        | reading
   1         | 2011/09/01 22:35 | 300
   1         | 2011/09/01 22:40 | 300
   1         | 2011/09/01 22:45 | 300
   1         | 2011/09/01 22:50 | 300
   1         | 2011/09/01 22:55 | 300
   1         | 2011/09/01 23:00 | 300
   1         | 2011/09/01 23:05 | 0
   1         | 2011/09/01 23:10 | 0
   ...`

Not sure if this is something that can be accomplished with Kinesis Analytics, I can actually do it querying a SQL table but I'm stuck with the fact that is streaming data.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with [Drools Kinesis Analytics](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B075MDR5DC) (managed service on Amazon):

Types:

```
package com.text;

import java.util.Deque;

declare EventA
    @role( event )
    id: int;
    timestamp: long;
    on: boolean;

    //not part of the message
    seen: boolean;
end

declare Session
    id: int @key;
    events: Deque;
end

declare Report
    id: int @key;
    timestamp: long @key;
    onInLast5Mins: int;
end
```

Rules:

```
package com.text;

import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;

declare enum Constants

    // 20 seconds - faster to test
    WINDOW_SIZE(20*1000);

    value: int;
end

rule "Reporter"
    // 20 seconds - faster to test
    timer(cron:0/20 * * ? * * *)
when
    $s: Session()
then
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int on = 0; //how long was on
    int off = 0; //how long was off
    int toPersist = 0; //last interesting event

    for (EventA a : (Deque<EventA>)$s.getEvents()) {
        toPersist ++;
        boolean stop = false;
        // time elapsed since the reading till now
        int delta = (int)(now - a.getTimestamp());
        if (delta >= Constants.WINDOW_SIZE.getValue()) {
            delta = Constants.WINDOW_SIZE.getValue();
            stop = true;
        }

        // remove time already counted
        delta -= (on+off);
        if (a.isOn())
            on += delta;
        else
            off += delta;

        if (stop)
            break;
    }

    int toRemove = $s.getEvents().size() - toPersist;
    while (toRemove > 0) {
        // this event is out of window of interest - delete
        delete($s.getEvents().removeLast());
        toRemove --;
    }

    insertLogical(new Report($s.getId(), now, on));
end

rule "SessionCreate"
when
    // for every new EventA
    EventA(!seen, $id: id) from entry-point events
    // check there is no session
    not (exists(Session(id == $id)))
then
    insert(new Session($id, new ArrayDeque()));
end

rule "SessionJoin"
when
    // for every new EventA
    $a : EventA(!seen) from entry-point events
    // get event's session
    $g: Session(id == $a.id)
then
    $g.getEvents().push($a);
    modify($a) {
        setSeen(true),
        setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
    };
end
```

Comment: I was checking Drools and seems pretty cool but want to achieve it using SQL for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using SQL with the [Stride HTTP API](https://www.stride.io/). You can chain together networks of continuous SQL queries and subscribe to streams of changes, as well as fire realtime webhooks if you want to take some kind of arbitrary action when this happens. See the [Stride API docs](http://www.stride.io/docs) for more info on this.